# Interior of difference of two sets

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading about some properties of interior operator. I dont know how to prove this property :
$$\operatorname{int}(A \setminus B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A) \setminus \operatorname{int}(B)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is in the interior of $A\setminus B$, there is some open set $O$ containing $x$ such that $O \subseteq A \setminus B \subseteq A$. So $O$ sits inside $A$, and so $x$ lies in $\operatorname{int}(A)$, and $x \notin B$ so $x \notin \operatorname{int}(B) (\subseteq B)$. Hence $x \in \operatorname{int}(A) \setminus \operatorname{int}{B}$ and done.

The inclusion can be strict as $A=\mathbb{R}, B= \mathbb{Q}$ shows: the left hand side then equals $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})= \emptyset$ while the right hand side equals $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}) \setminus \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \emptyset = \mathbb{R}$